# Como criar um desenho em formato de livro aberto e com conteúdo dentro?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, css3

Preciso de um desenho de um livro aberto com conteúdo dentro, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**APENAS COM CSS!**

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Abra a imagem no Photoshop, selecionando a área do texto, com a ferramenta de seleção, clique com o conta gotas na área branca do papel onde está o texto, com a cor selecionada tinja-a de branco com o comando alt + delete, depois com a ferramenta de fatia, corte essa imagem em três partes, como no exemplo abaixo:
[image: onde está a linha preta]

Agora crie o box e o css conforme abaixo:

```
 <style>
#livro {
   width: 868px;
   min-height: 550px;
   background: #fff4d6;
}
#livro .content {
 width: 868px;
 height: auto;
 background: url(imagens/content.jpg) center center repeat-y;
}
#livro .content p {
   color: #00777f;
   font-family: Arial, Verdana;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 20px 10px;
}
#livro .top {
 width: 868px;
 height: 49px;
 background: url(imagens/top.jpg) center top no-repeat;
 display:block;
}

#livro .bottom {
 width: 868px;
 height: 75px;
 background: url(imagens/bottom.jpg) center top no-repeat;
 display:block;
}
</style>

<div id="livro">
  <div class="top"></div>
   <div class="content"> <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, possim 
ullamcorper pro ea, error possim 
deterruisset vim te. In quo suas signiferumque, no sea debitis facilisi. Id doming ponderum interpretaris vim, 
ius an elitr adipiscing dissentias. Eu est agam concludaturque. Ut mea omnis clita scriptorem, nihil accumsan 
moderatius in mel. Te has offendit detraxit maiestatis, vel ut vide insolens accusamus. </p>
 <p>
Quo ei equidem nostrum, ad vis case assentior 
definitionem. Pro quod appareat ut, ei pro malis percipit instructior, vis ne nostrum posidonium. Ad vis harum latine, 
pro nullam rationibus ut, veri noluisse 
dissentias eum at. Pri in numquam dolores, at pro vocent praesent posidonium.
 </p>
 <p>
Ad duo libris platonem, mea ex accusam 
consequuntur. Aperiam evertitur duo at. Hendrerit mnesarchum ex his. Vix congue veniam at, ad veri postea incorrupte vix. Mei ex qualisque percipitur cotidieque.
 </p>
 <p>
Ex facilis accusam usu, ponderum 
intellegat an sit. Te pri persius 
efficiendi concludaturque. Liber 
salutatus adversarium ea vis. His ea quot ridens perfecto. Eum id vidit quando.
 </p>
 <p>
In sea iusto honestatis. Clita sensibus 
cum no, percipit recteque scriptorem vis 
cu. Erant graeci ne vel, omnis aperiam 
ne mei. At his eirmod cetero. </p>
</div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**Obs:** Se você quer usar somente CSS, use SVG, canvas ou converta as imagens em base64, aqui tem um site que faz isso por você:
http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php

Comment: Blz @IvanFerrer, curti sua idéia..

Comment: Neste caso também é possível utilizar svg. Tanto no caso do svg como no do canvas, tome cuidado com a compatibilidade entre navegadores, pois navegadores mais antigos podem não abri-las

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma div com o css background-image: , em seguida configure o padding para que o texto não ultrapasse os limites da página, se a "borda" do livro tiver uns 10 pixels, use uns 20 de padding. Em seguida coloque o conteúdo da div desejado. Não esqueça de deixar o tamanho da imagem igual ao da div

Ex:

```
<div style="background-image:url('livro.gif');padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px">Aqui vai o texto do livro</div>
```

Comment: Bacana a idéia! Ja tinha pensado nisso, mas queria fazer tudo com css. Obrigado!

Comment: Só usei css aí, ela somente está no div e vc precisa de algo para ter o conteúdo, ou coloque a imagem como um background no body msm

Comment: Sim, entendi sua colocação brother! Mas quero tudo com css.. Não usar imagem.

Comment: Se você quiser, basta converter as imagens em base64, que tudo vai passar a ser em css, também pode usar canvas ou svg, vai dar no mesmo.